# Sequelize.js findAll with include to search foreign_key makes page never load

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

**Description**

I have a simple database that consists of a Customer, Address, and Order. I'm trying to find all orders where the address is some string. For example I can provide the city or state and I want to lookup based on that.

**Orders Table:**
[image]

**Address Table:**
[image]

**Orders Model:**

```
module.exports = db.define('orders', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    repId: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER },
    totalItemCost: { type: Sequelize.DECIMAL(10,2), allowNull: false},
    shippingCost: { type: Sequelize.DECIMAL(10,2), allowNull: false},
    orderDate: { type: Sequelize.DATE, allowNull: false},
    isPaid: { type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN, allowNull: false},
    taxPercentage: { type: Sequelize.DECIMAL(10,4), allowNull: false},
}, {timestamps: false, freezeTableName: true, tableName: 'Orders'});
```

**Address Model:**

```
module.exports = db.define('address', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    firstName: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false},
    lastName: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false},
    city: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false},
    address: { type: Sequelize.STRING(256), allowNull: false},
    zip: { type: Sequelize.STRING(10), allowNull: false},
}, {timestamps: false, freezeTableName: true, tableName: 'Address'});
```

**Relations:**

```
var models = {};
models.Address = require("./models/address.js");
models.Customer = require("./models/customer.js");
models.Orders = require("./models/orders.js");

// Orders Relations
models.Orders.belongsTo(models.Customer, { foreignKey: { name: 'customerId', allowNull: false }});
models.Orders.belongsTo(models.Address, { foreignKey: { name: 'shippingAddressId', allowNull: false }});
```

**The Problem**

Say for example I want to find all orders where the city is Birchwood. I'm using include in my findAll command with the model set to my address and because I've specifically named my shipping address, setting the "as" statement. This results in the page never loading and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. If I remove the include command, all my orders load fine. I don't see any examples for include when "belongsTo" was used. When "hasMany" is used it looks like "association" is used instead of "foreign_key". Is that the problem why "as" isn't working?

```
models.Orders.findAll({
    where: where,
    include: [{
        model: models.Address, 
        as: 'shippingAddressId',
    }] 
}).then(function(orders) { 
    res.json(orders);
}).catch(function(err) {
    res.status(500).json({"error": err});
});
```

**EDIT 1**

I added in error handling for my query statement, but this now just outputs {"error":{}}. There error is blank so that's not very helpful. If I remove the "as: 'shippingAddressId'" line, then the model loads, and just puts the address under the field "address" in the json structure which is not desired. Adding a where clause to that causes it to return an empty object {}. I basically want include: [{ all: true, nested: true }] but also filtered on the relationship Address.

Comment: Something wrong with `json({"error": err});`. `err` must contain stack trace and err message. Even if this particular issue is solved, I would still recommend you to debug your code in debugger. And see what error shows there. And also find the way to print errors to console at least. Like `console.dir(err)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding the association to my relationships:

```
// Orders Relations
models.Orders.belongsTo(models.Customer, { as: 'customer', onDelete: 'CASCADE', foreignKey: { name: 'customerId', allowNull: false }});
models.Orders.belongsTo(models.Address, { as: 'shippingAddress', onDelete: 'CASCADE', foreignKey: { name: 'shippingAddressId', allowNull: false }});
models.Orders.belongsTo(models.PaymentMethod, { as: 'paymentMethod', onDelete: 'CASCADE', foreignKey: { name: 'paymentMethodId', allowNull: false }});
models.OrderItem.belongsTo(models.Orders, { as: 'order', onDelete: 'CASCADE', foreignKey: { name: 'orderId', allowNull: false }});
```

And then using that association name in my query:

```
models.Orders.findAll({
    where: where,
    include: [{
        model: models.Address,
        as: 'shippingAddress',
        where: {
            city: {like: "%Wedgewood%" }
        }
    }]
}).then(function(orders) { 
    res.json(orders);
}).catch(function(err) {
    res.status(500).json({"error": err});
});
```

I was under the impression that that association was automatically made.

Comment: Thanks, I solved this issue by this answer!

Answer (score 0):

Obviously there is an error in the query. Thats why `res.json(orders);` never called. I don't see error handling in you code. Take a look at http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/catch.html. When you will catch error, output it and see exactly whats going on.

Comment: I updated my question. The error is blank, but removing my "as" statement causes the data to load under a different column name.